# Does the Bundler 1.2.0 ruby version check obviate the need for a basic .rvmrc file?

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

Bundler 1.2.0.pre includes a new "ruby" DSL option.  According to [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions), they use this new Gemfile syntax to control which ruby version is used when you push your app.

Being pre-release, documentation for the new Bundler option is fairly thin on the ground at the moment, and the [Bundler 1.2 roadmap](https://gist.github.com/1228013) simply lists it as "ruby version check".

My question is: currently I use a one-line .rvmrc file in most of my projects, in which I only specify the ruby version for that project (eg. `rvm ruby-1.9.3`).  I don't use RVM gemsets or anything else (I prefer to vendor all of the required gems within the project, and let Bundler manage the dependencies).

Given my trivial RVM config, will the new "ruby" option in Bundler's DSL mean I no longer need to specify a .rvmrc file at all?  Or are they two different things?

(I do like the fact that RVM automatically switches the ruby version when I cd into my project...not sure if Bundler would do that, or if it just warns when the current version doesn't match?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the new `ruby` is a function and it will allow anything that finally evaluates to a string.

Unfortunately o read it you would need to use a `bundler` command which assumes you already have a ruby.

Instead RVM gives you two ways to defining ruby in `Gemfile`:

1) `ruby "1.9.3"` - simple strings

2) `#ruby=1.9.3-p125` - a comment when you want to use ruby code for `ruby` or when you want to specify patchlevel or gemset!:

```
#ruby=1.9.3
ruby ENV['RUBY_VERSION'] || '1.9.3'
```

Will allow bundler to work with any ruby loaded by RVM but by default will use **1.9.3** from `#ruby=`

Comment: Using `ENV['RUBY_VERSION']` somewhat defeats the underlying purpose, especially considering that the `ruby` directive tells services like Heroku which version of Ruby to use for deployment.

Comment: Ryan it's not my call, I have to deal with it in RVM, it's really hard because it's all ruby code and right now there is no ruby based tool for switching rubies - so of course it is not possible to read the version - but even we would have a ruby process the result can be distorted - and as you noticed I give the bad code as example why to use the comment, do you feel there is an note needed to advie users to not use it?